# Define Custom Object Lifecycle Hooks In Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop, activerecord, module

So I have a object and I want to define a lifecycle hook such as before_create, after_create, etc.

I want to call this after_retire and have it setup so I can do the following:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Active
  after_retire :method

  def method
   #do stuff
  end
end
```

So far I have a module setup like so but I keep getting a method undefined after_retire error on my User model.

```
module Active
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    define_callbacks :retire
    set_callback :retire, :after, :after_retire
    default_scope { where(:retired => false) }
    scope :retired, where(:retired => true)
  end

  def retire!
    run_callbacks :retire do
      update_attribute :retired, true
      update_attribute :retired_at, Time.now.to_datetime
    end
  end
end
```

How should I be setting this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The before/after_callback syntax is handled in ActiveModel::Callbacks through #define_model_callbacks. The raw ActiveSupport::Callbacks will require you to use #set_callback without any syntactic sugar:

```
module Active
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    define_callbacks :retire
    default_scope { where(:retired => false) }
    scope :retired, where(:retired => true)
  end

  def retire!
    run_callbacks :retire do
      update_attribute :retired, true
      update_attribute :retired_at, Time.now.to_datetime
    end
  end
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Active
  set_callback :retire, :after, :method

  def method
    #do stuff
  end
end
```

If you want to have the after/before syntax, since you are working with an ActiveRecord (and thus ActiveModel) class, you can use:

```
module Active
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    define_model_callbacks :retire
    default_scope { where(:retired => false) }
    scope :retired, where(:retired => true)
  end

  def retire!
    run_callbacks :retire do
      update_attribute :retired, true
      update_attribute :retired_at, Time.now.to_datetime
    end
  end
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Active
  after_retire :method

  def method
    #do stuff
  end
end
```

Comment: Also, you should probably use update_attributes(retired: true, retired_at: Time.now) to avoid an unnecessary extra DB call.